# Keyboard event gets lost in jlist

Tags: java, swing, focus, jlist, keyboard-events

When stuff is loading, the frame is being disabled.

```
void makeEnable(Container  parent, boolean enabled) {
    for(Component c : parent.getComponents()) {
        c.setEnabled(enabled);
        if(c instanceof Container) {
            makeEnable((Container)c, enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

But there is a problem with JList - when user selects item he can move through the list using up/down arrows. It becomes impossible after enabling and then disabling frame. The item is selected but user has to click on JList to use arrows again.

1. Do you know other solution to make application doesn't get input events ?
2. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: I know that some do it by showing/hiding a JGlassPane or JXLayerPane to capture all incoming events.

Comment: Have you tried to put the focus on the JList? I suspect that by disabling the frame, the JList looses the focus. When you re-enable the frame, you should also try to restore the Component that had the focus.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet This is it. requestFocus does the trick. Thanks for help.